# Libgit2Sharp : Get files associated with the initial (first) commit

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

How can I retrieve files that were part of the very first (initial) commit of a repository?

I'm currently using the following to find out files that are part of a commit (and it works). However, since the method need two parameters, what should I pass to get the files that are part of the fist commit? Or is there another method I need to use?

```
    repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(repo.Commits.ElementAt(i).Tree, repo.Commits.ElementAt(i + 1).Tree)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my requirement using the following:

```
                    //The tree object corresponding to the first commit in the repo
                    Tree firstCommit = repo.Lookup<Tree>(repo.Commits.ElementAt(i).Tree.Sha);
                    //The tree object corresponding to the last commit in the repo
                    Tree lastCommit = repo.Lookup<Tree>(repo.Commits.ElementAt(0).Tree.Sha);


                    var changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(lastCommit, firstCommit);
                    foreach (var item in changes)
                    {
                        if (item.Status != ChangeKind.Deleted)
                        {
                            //...This object (i.e. item) corresponds to a file that was part of the first (initial) commit...
                        }
                    }
```

Let me know if there is a better way...

Answer (score 3):

You can easily take a diff between the initial tree and a null tree to catch the files:

```
foreach (TreeEntryChanges change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(null, commit.Tree))
{
     Console.WriteLine("\t{0} :\t{1}", change.Status, change.Path);
}
```